# How to find an unique name to rename/archive old directories in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Whenever I do a new install, I install a new directory. I am having issues with installing over old directories and would now like to archive my old directories.

If `DirExists` returns true, I want to rename the directory from `Directory` to `DirectoryOld1`.

The issue I am having is how to check and iterate through the renaming process, so that if `DirectoryOld1` exists, rename the current directory to `DirectoryOld2` and so on.

Comment: Could you show a little code to show what you have working now? Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: What is `DirExistsWarning`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to backup an existing directory to a unique (incremented) name. Right?

This will do:

```pascal
function BackupDir(OldName: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := 1;
  { Find a unique index }
  while DirExists(OldName + IntToStr(I)) do
  begin
    Inc(I);
  end;

  { And rename }
  Result := RenameFile(OldName, OldName + IntToStr(I)); 
end;
```

Comment: Is Inc() IncrementSharedCount()?

Comment: No, `Inc(I)` is functionally equivalent to `I := I + 1`. See http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/inc.html