# Rename/backup file to a random name in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I know that I can rename any file with:

```pascal
function RenameFile(const OldName, NewName: string): Boolean;
```

I already have this:

```pascal
RenameFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\myfile.dll'), ExpandConstant('{app}\Myfile.dll.old'));
```

Which I can rename my file to any desired name, but in this case I need to rename it with a random generated name, I tried to use: `ExpandConstant('{app}\Myfile.dll.{tmp}'));` to get the random name generated by `{tmp}` but that did not work.

Is there any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Random` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_random):

```pascal
ExpandConstant('{app}\Myfile.dll.' + IntToStr(Random(1000)))
```

---

Though, it does not prevent you from generating an already existing name. You should at least test, if the generate name exists. And if it does, then try a new random name. But then it makes no sense to use a random name. You can use incremental numbers instead, as those have better semantics.

See [How to find an unique name to rename/archive old directories in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35900787/850848).